# How to search a linked list character by character to find a word?

Tags: c

I have created a linked list which enters a word character by character from a string. Each character represents a node inside of the linked list. For example, Ian is nice would appears as:
I->A->N-> ->i->s-> ->n->i->c->e->terminates with new line.

I am attempting to find "IAN" when I search and locate how many times Ian would appear in the nodes of the linked list.

When I used my current code, I will search for the desired word. It will enter and begin search the linked list and it won't find any occurrences.

I've attempted to search the linked list as strings, but that makes little since in this context the link list consists of characters.

I have also tried searching for words character by character, but they return nothing.

I am now attempting to search for the word inside of the function, and it now returns an infinite loop of search. Even though I've attempted to end it at new line, and it's not counting the number of occurrences.

```
node* Find(char findCharacter){
    node *nodePtr = headNode;
    int occurrences = 0;
    int index;
    const int arraySize = 51;
    char findWord[arraySize];

    printf("Enter the word that you would like to find: ");
    gets_s(findWord);
    printf("\n");

    while((nodePtr != NULL) && (nodePtr->character != findCharacter)){

        for(index = 0; nodePtr->character != '\n'; index++){
            if(findWord == &findWord[index]){
                nodePtr = nodePtr->nextNode;
            }
            else{

            }
        }

        occurrences = occurrences + 1;

    }

    printf("number of occurrences: %d\n", occurrences);
    return nodePtr;
}

int main() {
    const int arraySize = 201;
    char entryString[arraySize];
    int index;


    /*
     * Let the user enter a string to start the program
     * */
    printf("Enter a user string: ");
    gets_s(entryString);
    printf("\n");
    int length = strlen(entryString);

    for(index = 0; index < length; index++){
        Find(entryString[index]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the user enters: "Ian Ian is a great student."
and the user attempts to find: Ian
The program is supposed to return:
The user has entered: " Ian Ian is a great student."

"The number of occurrences for Ian is 2"

Comment: It's a bit odd to carry a newline in an extra, unnecessary list node.  A more typical approach would be to simply terminate the list after the last non-newline character by having a null pointer in `nextNode`.

Comment: You don't need an intermediate array. Instead, walk the list and for each node test whether the list starting at that point starts with "Ian". (Ideally, this test is a separate function so that whatever the outcome, your first-level traversal will not be affected.)

Comment: @M Oehm, the linked list is stored as a series of characters. So it is not stored as Ian is Cool. It is stored as: I->a->n-> ->i->s-> ->c->o->o->l->NULL. So I would have to go through the linked list character by character in order to examine if the word Ian pops up in the linked list.

Comment: Yes, I have understood that. The subfunction should of course also walk the list, but with a second node pointer.

Comment: Also, the `Find` function you posted is strange. It looks like a function to find the first node where a character occurs where the string search is half-heartedly shoehorned in. You probably shouldn't primpt for the string inside that function. Do that outside and then make your function just count the occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have working code to set up your linked list. A simple function to count how often a single letter occurs would look like this:

```
int count_chars(node *nodePtr, char findme)
{
    int occurrences = 0;

    while (nodePtr) {
        if (nodePtr->character == findme) {
            occurrences++;
        }
    }

    return occurrences;
}
```

(Note: I've chosen to pass the head node to the function instead of using a global head pointer. That will allow you to have more than one linked list in your program. That means that you could even implement your search word "Ian" as linked list.)

Instead of finding a string anywhere in the list, let's first write some code that tests whether a linked list begins with a certain word. Walk the list and the string simultaneously and check for mismatches. Becsuae we require all of the string, but not all of the list to match, we control the loop with the string:

```
int startswith(node *nodePtr, const char *findme)
{
    while (*findme) {
        if (nodePtr == NULL || *findme != nodePtr->character) {
            return 0;                     // mismatch!
        }

        nodePtr = nodePtr->nextNode;      // next node in list
        findme++;                         // next char in string
    }

    return 1;                             // all chars match
}
```

But you want to find the string anywhere, not just at the beginning. Each node in the list can be considered the head node of a sublist that starts at that node. So if your list holds "cat", the nodes in the list hold the sublists "cat", "at", and "t" respectively. With the function above, you can check for your word at each node. The code looks very similar to the first code snippet above where we have just counted chars.

```
int count_strings(node *nodePtr, const char *findme)
{
    int occurrences = 0;

    while (nodePtr) {
        if (startswith(nodePtr, findme)) {
            occurrences++;
        }
    }

    return occurrences;
}
```

One remark about code design: Don't try to do everything into your function. If the string you search for comes from user input, don't make that part of the function. Instead, do that separately: read the input, then test that input with `count_strings`. That way, your function can be used in other contexts than just your specialised case. (The same holds more or less for passing in the head node as parameter.)

Comment: Apologies, but how exactly do I call the count_strings function in main? Would I called it count_strings(headNode, charArray[index]) ?

Comment: If `char charArray[SIZE]` is the string you take as user input, perhaps from `fgets`, then you should call it `n = count_strings(headNode, charArray);` and then output `n`. (But that's really basic stuff.)

Comment: I actually understand the char charArray[Size]. But for whatever reason, the function count_strings won't allow me to call it. One of the parameters is preventing me from properly calling the function in main. As it stands, my current code is: Find(headNode, searchWord[index]);

Comment: Read my comment again: There's no `[index]`. `searchWord[index]` is a single character at that index. `searchWord` is an array of characters that ends with a null character. In C, that is called a string. (Like a string of pearls, just with characters instead.)

Comment: I think I may know what the problem is. I've created a doubly linked list, and I'm assuming that this searching method only accounts for a singly linked list? I don't know if this would change anything.

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem. A doubly linked list can be traversed both forwards and backwards. All the code here traverses the list only forwards, but a doubly linked list can do that. If the base implementation of your list (which we can't know about) is sane, my suggestions should work. Period. Don't go looking for problems where there aren't any.

Comment: @M Oehm I solved what was going wrong. It was how my function was taking in strings. Basically gets stores an array but doesn't create a string. I now understand why you use fgets.